# Is it possible to add math formulas to posts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, markdown

Is it possible to add math formulas to posts on Stack Overflow?

I think I've seen this in a few places. Is there a way to include [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) formulas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. This is possible on various math-related Stack Exchange sites ([Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/about), [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/about), and [Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/about)), but not on Stack Overflow itself - the rationale being that the overhead of [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) wouldn't be worth it for a site where the feature isn't essential.

Comment: mathjax is about ~500kb of overhead -- per page load unless it's being properly cached.

Comment: By looking at this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-stack-overflow-question) and this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73504/how-to-enter-formulas-on-math-or-cstheory), I understood that it IS possible to write formulas, I even used it ... Why you say it is not ?

Comment: @SAAD Your second link is about math and cstheory, not about Stack Overflow. As I explained in this very answer, what's described there does not work on Stack Overflow. Your first link describes how to add images to SO posts. While it's of course perfectly possible to add formulas as images to an SO post, that's clearly not what I was talking about in this answer.