# How do I enter formulas on 'Mathematics' or 'Theoretical Computer Science'?

Tags: support, markdown, mathjax

The help icon only leads to a general Markdown reference.

The way to enter formulas should be mentioned, preferably in a separate section and with a link to a Tex reference.

Comment: How to enter a forumla isn't obvious. Either that or the preview box isn't evaluating the formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both *[Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour)* and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) have formatting help links for this in the "How to Format" section on the right hand side of the page, both of which point [here](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/).

On the meta ste of *Mathematics* you will also find *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)*.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the case in mt browser: http://twitpic.com/3l71he/full What am I missing?

Comment: @9000: Put the cursor focus in the body text box: the right hand side changes. I agree the UI isn't ideal.

Comment: Math doesn't have that link anymore. I went to ask page and searched "format" no results

Comment: pointing to the homepage of mathjax isn't a good way of helping someone. Also any demos or instruction on this subject is missing from the advanced markdown help