# How do you do summation notation in MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

For example, sum for every *k* from 0 to *n*.

How would I do this properly in MathJax format on a site that supports MathJax?

Comment: Hi dat boi, welcome to Meta! I'm not sure which search brought you here but the problem you describe will not be answered on this specific site. To get an answer from users that have the expertise about the topic of your question you'll have to find and then re-post on the [proper site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Check [How do I ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and [What is on topic](/help/on-topic) on the *target* site to make sure your post is in good shape. Your question is definitely off-topic on [Meta](/help/whats-meta) and is better deleted here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you. I am new so I do not know which site my question should go on. can you please tell me?

Comment: Actually - that looks like an actual formatting question. It could use a little love but I'm actually leaning on this being on topic

Comment: @JourneymanGeek assuming it is on-topic, it would be a duplicate of [How do I enter formulas on 'Mathematics' or 'Theoretical Computer Science'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73510/165773)

Comment: Plausible, but dosen't make it off topic. Different, potentially valid close reason, but seems fairly specific

Comment: Please read the [mathjax tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info).

Comment: Related: *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enter formulas on 'Mathematics' or 'Theoretical Computer Science'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73504/how-do-i-enter-formulas-on-mathematics-or-theoretical-computer-science)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\sum' command:

```
$\sum_{k=0}^n k = \frac{n^2-n}{2}$
```

There's a [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/228959) on Mathematics Meta where you can practice.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the preferred notation in accordance with ISO 80000-2, use

```
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}$$
```

[image]

However, the following notations are also used

```
$$\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}$$

$$\sum\limits_i {a_i}$$

$$\sum\nolimits_i {a_i}$$

$$\sum {a_i}$$
```

[image]