# How can I write a math formula in a post?

Tags: support, markdown

I want to ask something that contains a mathematical formula.

How can I write the equation? Is there a page that shows the syntax?

I thought there must be some syntax like in Wikipedia or something...

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73504/how-to-enter-formulas-on-math-or-cstheory - but I don't think the syntax is implemented on SO

Comment: It's strange that stackoverflow does not support math formulas directly, like MathExchange or CrossValidate.

Comment: @qed it would [severely increase load times for Stack Overflow pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60020/295232) for only very occasional benefit.

Comment: Now https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I'm not sure why Simon deleted his answer, but it was right, you can use the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/). For example, this:

```
![foo+bar](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=foo%2bbar)
```

becomes:

[image: foo+bar]

---

### Second formula:

```
![\sqrt{foo}](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csqrt%7Bfoo%7D)
```

becomes

[image: \sqrt{foo}]

Comment: Just to make this complete, an online TEXT editor: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: This doesn't work well when you have more than 1 formula.

Comment: @Yochai I just tried it in an edit; what issue are you having?

Comment: tried to put 4 formulas, only the first showed.

Comment: I need to substitute `)` with `%29` to make it work in preview when I type the answer. But even if I do so, it doesn't work when I save it and view it. @YochaiTimmer 's answer works for me.

Comment: This answer is now outdated, Stack Overflow now accepts LaTeX Phrases. (See Mehrad's answer)

Comment: @JanMoritz Stack Overflow still doesn't. Certain topic sites like Physics and Math Exchange do.

Comment: I guess this is an outdated answer; I found that I can follow the instructions here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for stat stack Exchange site

Answer (score 75):

Ok, best combination I found is doing something like what Michael suggested.
But it's easier to reference the link at the bottom.
So, go to this site: [Online LaTex Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)
Create your formula.  Use this site and encode it for URL safety: [URL Encoder/Decoder](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/querylanguage.html#plainText)

Take the result and prepend it with the following URL: `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=`

Then reference it to your post:

```
This is a formula ![formula][1]
Another formula: ![another][2]

  [1]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csum_%7B23%7D%5E%7B43%7D
  [2]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial%7D%7B%5Cpartial%20x%7D%7D
```

It will show like this:

This is a formula [image: formula]

Another formula: [image: another]

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is not as good as directly from LaTeX...

Comment: +1 I was having trouble getting this to work using `chart.googleapis.com` although I was able to get this work using the URL encoded link from `codecogs` just fine. I was using it for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20288006/1708801) answer, any idea why?

Comment: The latex editor you mentioned has an option for "URL (encoded)" that has been adequate to bypass the encoder for me so far. Saves one tab switch.

Comment: chart.googleapis actually doesn't support full LaTeX, just some simple subset. -- on the other hand, images from `https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?<formula>` ([for example](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csqrt%7B5%7D)) doesn't display well in stack overflow's dark mode.

Answer (score 40):

**LaTeX Phrases**

[Some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/295232) (mainly the scientific ones) use MathJax to render LaTeX. You can use single dollar signs to delimit inline equations, and double dollars for blocks:

The *Gamma function* satisfying `$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N$` is defined through the Euler integral

```
$$ \Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\,. $$
```

And you'll see the results as:
[image]

**To create a LaTeX phrase** you can go to an [online LaTeX Equation Editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Comment: It doesn't work on stackoverflow.

Comment: It works on a lot of stackexhange sites such as cross-validated, which are math intensive.

Comment: It works on mathematics stack as well.

Comment: It works, but how can I get the formula inlined, right now it comes out as block display, but when you want to refer in the text to variables with index or overline or simple terms, you want them inlined, not display block presented. How to do that?

Comment: Funny, it doesn't work even on... https://tex.stackexchange.com/ :-/ :-/

Answer (score 21):

1. Formulate your equation using [the CodeCogs tool](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).
2. Right-click the generated image and select "Copy image location" or similar.
3. On Stack Overflow, insert the image as so: `![equation](imageUrl)`

Thus:

```
![E=mc^2](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?E%3Dmc%5E2)
```

Becomes:

> [image: E=mc^2]

Answer (score 6):

Using WYSIWYG editor like [Mathcha Editor](https://www.mathcha.io/)

First, using this website to insert math equation (support import from latex)

Second, export to image/latex....to share
Or login to the website and share without limitation (auto-generate a link). There is Mathcha Editor:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome..

Comment: Is this a opensource project? Based on neovim or something? i couldnt find information on github etc..

Comment: Tis is a formula $\psi .\psi ^{\ast }$